# How to play drm contents in cobalt

Tags: drm, cobalt, widevine

I am developing using cobalt master.
I want to play the drm contents using cobalt. but as far as i know, cobalt(open-source) is not integrated with widevine or playready due to license.
So I have to the widevine integrating.. But I don't know what to do..

Below is question lists. I'd really appreciate it if your guys could answer this.

1. I found the sources about widevine in the cobalt source tree('cobalt/src/starboard/shared/widevine')
   I think it is about widevine porting. then I just need to put in the widevine.so or the widevine source. 
   Is it right?
2. I made a ce_cdm(it is widevine 3.5 source) derectory in 'cobalt/src/third_party' and then tried 'cobalt/build/gyp_cobalt -C debug linux-x64x11' but following message is printed the Terminal.

```
    $cobalt/build/gyp_cobalt -C debug linux-x64x11 
 gyp: Dependency '/home/amedia/cobalt4/cobalt/src/third_party/boringssl/boringssl.gyp:crypto#host' not found while trying to load target /home/amedia/cobalt4/cobalt/src/starboard/shared/widevine/widevine3.gyp:protoc#host
```

I have no idea what this means...

3. Please let me know if your guys have a guide or a way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From the gyp errors it looks like the version of widevine you have depends on boringssl which is not currently supported by Cobalt 19. And you might have some trouble integrating boringssl because it is a fork of openssl which is used by multiple components in Cobalt 19.

It might not be too difficult to replace openssl with boringssl. And maybe you can find a version of widevine that's also compatible with openssl, though I'm not sure about the feasibility.
Please also stay tuned to Cobalt's release announcements. We regularly upgrade our third party libraries and you should find new Cobalt releases easier to integrate with additional libraries.